# Is there a way to create an RSS feed for a Facebook group

Tags: facebook, rss, facebook-groups

Can we create a RSS feed for a Facebook group?

Basically, I want to display the latest happenings of a Facebook group on a web page with some other RSS feeds like a blog, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Group to RSS app on Facebook

http://apps.facebook.com/groups_to_rss/#_=_

Comment: as of 2020 this link is dead.

Answer (score 5):

You can access using Graph API. However you will need some access token with enough privileges to read the group stream.

e.g.: `https://graph.facebook.com/<group_id>/feed?access_token=<access_token>`

Sample output

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "2204300302_10150259728120303",
         "from": {
            "name": "Tiana Ellis",
            "id": "761409187"
         },
         "to": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "version": 0,
                  "name": "I just lost \"The Game\"",
                  "id": "2204300302"
               }
            ]
         },
         "message": "All day, everyday...",
         "type": "status",
         "created_time": "2011-08-08T18:22:42+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-08-08T18:22:42+0000"
      },
....
   ],
   "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/<group_id>/feed?access_token=<access_token>&limit=25&since=1312827762",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/<group_id>/feed?access_token=<access_token>&limit=25&until=1311913588"
   }
}
```

Source: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/#feed

Answer (score 2):

You can use a wallflux of your group: http://www.wallflux.com

> Wall Flux, the tool which helps you to export Facebook Page and Group Walls to RSS 2.0 feeds.
>
> Due to privacy settings, Wall Flux does not work out of the box for closed Facebook Groups. But with a small action from your side (adding us to your closed group) you can access the Wall Flux-feed just like that of an open Facebook Group.

Disclaimer: I'm affiliated with Wallflux

Comment: Do I need to be the owner of the group to "add you" to the group?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it with a group, but you can do it with a Facebook Page. Then just use the "Subscribe via RSS" link on the left side of the page, or follow this convention:

```
http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=[PAGE ID]&format=rss20
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to use the Facebook API I do not think there is a way to get a RSS feed. I was searching for solutions too and WallFlux is not providing any RSS feeds at the moment. By the way, their Facebook group RSS feeds are not always working correctly too.

After searching and trying I got something working. You may visit this page to find out how to use it: [my personal blog](https://about.tomdings.com/creating-rss-feeds-from-facebook-groups/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).